# X-ray diffraction imaging algorithm and peak finding codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Finding bin center in a histogram

Hi, I am trying to write a function in python that gets an array and put into a histogram and then sum over all the values in each bins in that histogram. In order to find the bin centers, I wrote these two lines below in two different codes.
Does anyone know why these two line give two different results? The first one gives an array with length of bin_values but the 2nd one gives a 1d array. I was expecting that both should work the same.

first code:

```
q = np.array([(bin_edges[i] + bin_edges[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(bin_values))])
```

second code:

```
for i in range(len(bin_values)):
    q = np.array([(bin_edges[i] + bin_edges[i+1]/2)])
```

Comment: where is your data? [mcve]?

Comment: @PatrickArtner The data comes from bin_edges that has a shape of (881,) and bin_values that has a shape of (880,) and I want the q to have the same shape as bin_values. With the first code, I get the shape of (880,) but the second code gives only a 1d array and I was wondering what is the difference between these two code and why they act differently.